# ¿Cómo puedo crear una "caja" para poner dentro elementos?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Acabo de empezar con SceneBuilder y estoy tratando de hacer este ejercicio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no sé cómo hacer el efecto de "caja" que encierra los campos "1st Player O: " y "2nd Player X:"

Comment: Hola, llevas tiempo en el sitio, recuerda realizar tus preguntas con base en [ask], si quieres opiniones o sugerencias puedes preguntar en [chat],saludos.

Comment: puede ser un GridPane  con Text y TextField